# Passing loading variable state to navbar component from all other components

Tags: angular, httprequest

When doing a HTTP request, I want to change my logo in my nav by a loading icon.

app.component.html:

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

What I would like is that all page in `router-outlet` can change a variable called loading that is defined inside `nav.component.ts` that would define wether the loading icon shows or not.

How should I do it ?

Comment: Write an HTTP interceptor (this is described in the HTTP guide). Emit an event from a Subject when a request is sent. Emit another event from the subject when a response comes back. Subscribe to this subject from the navbar, and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks :) Do you have the link of the HTTP guide ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http